# Install4j: window positioning

Tags: java, install4j

How do you position your installer window on the screen?

By default it is centered, which is fine in most cases. However, I am running multiple mini-installers (all created by Install4j, but which can be ran as standalones) during the installation process, and all these installers stack themselves on the same portion of the screen. As a result, it is very confusing for the end user, since they all have a "Finish" screen, and from their point of view there was only 1 window (or installer).

I would like to do a little offset or something, but couldn't find any properties to achieve that, besides resizing the window (which is kind of a bad workaround)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the "Post-activation" script of your first screen to

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Util.getParentWindow().setLocation(0, 0);
    }
});
```

to change the location of the installer window.